# Release an object in a non-ARC project, object is declared in an ARC library

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting, release

Well I am working on a non-ARC project, but use [Philipp Kyeck's socketio library](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) which is written using ARC. I am using the method explained in [this](http://www.seriousmonster.com/mixing-arc-and-non-arc-code-with-static-libraries/) tutorial merge non-ARC project and ARC library.

In my ViewController file I am initializing the socket using

```
 SockIO *chatSockIO = [[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
```

and when I need to disconnect, I call

```
[chatSockIO disconnect];
```

which results socketIODidDisconnect delegate method to fire.

```
- (void) socketIODidDisconnect:(SocketIO *)socket{
   [chatSockIO release]; ==> is this call needed?
}
```

Now my question is about the line `[chatSockIO release]`. **Should we need to release an object which itself is defined in ARC mode, but is used in a non-ARC project?**

Now when I tried the release, I got an exception saying

```
-[SocketIO retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6fec370
```

but when I commented out that line, I am getting a memory leak and **dealloc in my library object not getting called at all**

## Bounty Time!!

Forget the library I mentioned, crash in my code and leaks.. **What is the usual practice when using an object defined using ARC method, in a non-ARC project. Should I only alloc it, or should I alloc and release it after use?**

## EDIT:Some more info.

I run zombie instrument on the crash, and this is what it had to say.. It shows the call to alloc and release functions.

```
#   Address     Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp       Size    Responsible Library     Responsible Caller
0   0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Malloc      1       00:09.700.274   64      MyProject           -[MyViewController sendRequestForSocketIOPush]
1   0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      2       00:09.700.317   0       MyProject           -[SocketIO initWithDelegate:]
2   0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     1       00:09.700.320   0       MyProject           -[SocketIO initWithDelegate:]
3   0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      2       00:09.700.440   0       Foundation          -[NSURLConnectionInternal initWithInfo:]
4   0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      3       00:10.413.717   0       Foundation          -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]
5   0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     2       00:10.413.761   0       Foundation          -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:]
6   0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      3       00:10.413.797   0       Foundation          -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]
7   0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     2       00:10.413.811   0       Foundation          -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:]
8   0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      3       00:10.413.816   0       Foundation          -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]
9   0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     2       00:10.415.087   0       Foundation          -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:]
10  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      3       00:10.415.214   0       Foundation          -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]
11  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     2       00:10.415.216   0       Foundation          -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:]
12  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     1       00:10.415.275   0       Foundation          -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:]
13  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      2       00:10.969.432   0       GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
14  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     1       00:10.969.433   0       GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
15  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      2       00:10.969.434   0       GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
16  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     1       00:10.969.456   0       GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
17  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      2       00:10.969.459   0       GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
18  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      3       00:10.969.488   0       Foundation          -[NSCFTimer initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]
19  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     2       00:10.976.115   0       MyProject           -[SocketIO setTimeout]
20  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      3       00:10.976.125   0       Foundation          -[NSCFTimer initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]
21  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     2       00:10.976.161   0       GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
22  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      3       00:13.935.328   0       GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
23  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     2       00:13.935.373   0       MyProject           -[SocketIO setTimeout]
24  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Retain      3       00:13.935.399   0       Foundation          -[NSCFTimer initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]
25  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     2       00:13.935.685   0       MyProject           -[SocketIO onDisconnect]
26  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     1       00:13.935.705   0       MyProject           -[MyViewController socketIODidDisconnect:]
27  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Release     0       00:13.935.716   0       GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
28  0x72d5da0   SocketIO    Zombie      -1      00:13.936.298   0       GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
```

Comment: No need to change the ARC class file just add `-fobjc-arc` in the compiler flag of the class file

Comment: @Sumanth Unfortunately I have a library that written in ARC, and that library uses 3 or 4 other libraries all follows ARC. This static library method is better in that case I guess.. Also even if I classify all my ARC class files using compiler flags, I am allocing and using sockIO object in my project file, which written in non-ARC mode. And if I do alloc/retain in a non-ARC file, I must release.

Comment: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/ - this is really great tutorial about [mixing] ARC/non-ARC code! Also do you aware of `NS_RETURNS_NON_RETAINED` and `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` ?

Comment: @Олег Трахман Good post.. Reading..

Comment: What does the stack track for the `[SocketIO retain]` look like?  Is that call made from your code or the library code?

Comment: No it is not called from my code..

Comment: According to convention, you should not release the object passed to your function... so perhaps there's a leak in the library? It might be useful to see if there are any other objects leaking at the same rate. (i.e. run your operation 11 times, and look for any objects that leak 11 times--that may be a clue) You may be leaking another object somewhere else that is causing SocketIOs to pile up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To answer your question:**

If you use an ARC-managed object from non-ARC code, you use it just as you would use a non-ARC object: If you create or retain it, you have to release or autorelease it.

**Regarding your issue:**

In on of your comments you mentioned that you tried to fix the problem with initializing like this

```
self.chatSockIO = [[[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
```

and in `socketIODidDisconnect`

```
self.chatSockIO = nil;
```

That should work fine, provided that the `chatSockIO` property has `retain` semantics, and that only one `SocketIO` object is used at a time.

The Zombie output gives a hint on what's going wrong:

- In the second to last line, you release the object, the retain count drops to 0, and the object is deallocated. That is what you would expect.
- In the last line however, it is tried to retain the object from the run loop. You know it's a retain because of the exception you get without `NSZombie`.
- That means although you are done with the object, it still receives calls from somewhere. This is unexpected.

It could be either something in your code, or an error in one of the libraries you are using. Just a hunch: In `SocketIO.m` replace these lines in `-onDisconnect`

```
if (_webSocket != nil) {
    [_webSocket close];
}
```

with

```
if (_webSocket != nil) {
    [_webSocket close];
    _webSocket.delegate = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve your problem, but in any case its usually a TERRIBLE idea to release an object in a delegate call - it may get dealloc'd while still doing work, and particularly if the object is under ARC, may not have a dealloc method.

So convert your close delegate call to this:

```
- (void) socketIODidDisconnect:(SocketIO *)socket
{
   chatSockIO.delegate = nil; // don't want any more messages
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_gueue(), ^{ self.chatSockIO = nil; }); // typed in text editor
   // your question - is the release needed? Well, under virtually every scenario yes, but I don't know this framework
}
```

Whether this fixes your problem or not, you should be doing the release in this manner - on the main thread AFTER the delegate has returned. If you look at your code, you should do EXACTLY with this ARC class as you would with a normal class. The interoperability is excellent, I used several NON-ARC projects in my ARC app, and others have successfully done the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I wouldn't mix ARC and non-ARC expect small small chunks of code. I wasted way to much time to try to find leaks and crash bugs.

If you can't convert your program to ARC, consider using the non-ARC version of sockIO: https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc/tree/non-arc

That will probably save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: I first used non ARC version, but it still uses cocoa-websocket where as ARC version upgraded to use SocketRocket. That is why I was forced to use ARC version.

Comment: Also, Using ARC classes in non-ARC project using static library method is working well. I can neglect the leak which I mentioned since that part of the code executes only once in my application and the magnitude of leak is very small. I can just comment out the release line and go on.. But I just wanted to know what is the proper procedure when merging ARC and non-ARC file using static library method.

Comment: I would expect that you actually need to release it. But maybe your problem here is that you don't hold a reference to the SockIO object while running the rest of the code? Try adding the sockIO object to a strong property and add back the release?

Answer (score 0):

I had felt similar issues. I solved this by setting `@property(nonatomic, retain)`  over the class. In your case it should be,

in .h

```
  @property(nonatomic, retain) SockIO *socketIO;
```

in .m

```
   @synthesize socketIO;
   chatSockIO = [[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
```

And you wont get crash your App again !

Comment: Well I did as you suggest, I made chatSockIO a property and retained it.. When I alloc, I changed the code to `self.chatSockIO = [[[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self]autoRelease];`. In `socketIODidDisconnect ` delegate method I replaced `[chatSockIO release]` with `self.chatSockIO = nil`. Still I am getting the crash..

Comment: No - don't use self.chatSockIO - you then doubly retain it. The example code is structured so the ivar is set with the retained value.

Comment: @DavidH nope.. I am using autorelease along with self.chatSockIO.. Have you noticed?

Answer (score 0):

ARC and non ARC objects mix fine. Classes that are implemented using ARC can safely be used from non-ARC code. Whenever there's an ownership error the problem is probably in your code.

Without seeing code it's not possible to find the error but it's probably some simple over-release.

Look at all the places in `MyProject` where the Instruments trace shows a `Release` event, like `-[SocketIO setTimeout]`, `-[SocketIO onDisconnect]` and `-[MyViewController socketIODidDisconnect:]`. Check if there are improper ownership transfers, like assigning an instance variable handled by a retain property or similar.

Comment: In the 3 methods you mentioned, only in `-[MyViewController socketIODidDisconnect:]` I am releasing the socket io object. It is only get called once (that was my first port of call, thinking somehow the delegate is called twice for one disconnect, and release the object twice). Regarding full code, there are nothing much I left out.. The only other usage of the object `socketIO` is when data is received or sent. I am not doing any retain or release or auto release there. Also the functions `setTimeout` and `onDisconnect` are functions inside the library and not directly called by me.

Comment: Also this might be a bug in library, as it overreleases the thing somewhere.. I am not sure about that though.. That is why I rephrased is as a more generic question.

Comment: Right, it looks like the GraphicsServices `GSEventRunModal` functions actually perform the over-release. You should look at the individual stacks in the retain history of these calls to understand why they are performed. It might well be a problem of the library you are using.

Comment: He was not nixing the delegate when he released the socket object, and thus he COULD be getting two of those messages and double releasing. I suggested he should nil the delegate at an appropriate place (along with a deferred release in the main thread).

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a project that I did something similar and the way I solved it was to switch the non-ARC project to ARC. Xcode transfers everything over for you and for me solved all my memory leaks and other issues.

To change over to ARC you need to:

**1.** Click Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC

**2.** Click your projects target and in the drop down, select the files you want to convert to ARC

**3.** Click Check once you have selected the right files

**4.** Click next and wait until conversion is done.

**5.** Click the "Update" button to update your code.

**6.** Review your code

Hope that helps. It helped me